# Handling different kinds of files efficiently?

Tags: java, io, stream, filestream

I am developing a Java application that deals with large number of files with varying sizes. (eg: millions of files with one line or single file with millions of lines). Which is the most efficient method to handle both these scenarios?

Comment: Please elaborate in details, like type of file and what operations you are targetting here

Comment: Don't load the entire file in memory but process it as your read it, in a streaming fashion. Thats the fastest regardless of the file size, but you may not notice the difference for small files very much.

Comment: Depends on how the application deals with the files?
a. Is it limited to only listing?
b .Does it read a single file at a time, or all files at the same time.
Reading a files content can be optimized depending on the file size though.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to process millions of files is to have a fast SSD drive. The cost of opening and closing each file is significant, and likely to be a bottleneck. A HDD might only allow you to read ~100 files per second no matter how small they are.

For processing file in the giga-bytes, you might want to process portions of the file concurrently, although how you do that depends on the format and what you need to do with the file. You should be able to read the file at a rate of about 50 - 200 MB/s depending on what you are doing with it.